# Aligning two objects on left one right, on the same level

Tags: html

How do I Align two images so they are equal, but on different sides of the page?

Any Help?

Comment: float: left; and float: right;? Or isn't this what you mean to do?

Comment: I align a image right and one left but it isn't displayed on the same line, its sort of a few centimetres down, I think there is a way called wrapping? or adding them to a layer?

Comment: Please, post your code, It'd be easier to help you

Comment: @JavaNovice. they will be assuming you don't have them in a div or other block element, otherwise just add `display: inline-block` to the divs.

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsbin.com/weyerufe/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image1.png" style="float:left">
<img src="image2.png" style="float:right">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this as well,

```
img{float:left;}
img+img{float:right;}
```

Here is the **[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/weyerufe/1/)**

Comment: If the solution works for you then you can close this by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

example of your code

```
<div class="mainwrap">
<a id="left_img"><img src="1.jpg"></a>
<a id="right_img"><img src="2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

ur css

```
.mainwrap
{
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin:auto;
}
#left_img
{
float:left;
}
#right_img
{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
<a id="leftImg" style="float:left;"><img src="1.jpg"></a>
<a id="rightImg" style="float:right;"><img src="2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```